# Code 'for' 'in' 'not in' not working, how to fix so it respects answers give prior to commands?

Tags: python, list, syntax, pycharm, syntax-error

I've been trying to make a little and simple game where you walk and you find different stuff, but for some reason when I type the for and in commands it doesn't respect what the answer was in b

```
#
print('You may now begin your quest because I said so')
print('You must choose a number between 1 and 10, each number must be selected only once')
a = int(input('How many block do you wanna walk?'))
if a == 1:
    print('Really? 1 block? LUL')
if a == 2:
    b = str(input("You've found a hole, it is too dark too see what's on it though, do you wish to explore?"))
    hang = ("yes")
for b in hang:
    print('You fell and died.')
else:
    print('Ok then, keep going.')
```

As you can see it's pretty simple but it always displays both `for b in hang:` and `else`
I did try creating another list `fk = ("no")` and change the `else` `for for b in fk:    print('Ok then, keep going')` but it doesn't work either, I also tried putting `for b not in hang: print('Ok then, keep going')` but the ladder simply doesn't work

Comment: are you looking for ```if```? for b in hang iterates through every letter in the word.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try:

```
if b.startswith('y'):
    print('you fell and died')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from reading your code, looks like you are iterating the letters `y`, `e` and `s`

What exactly are you trying to do?

if `hang` is supposed to be a tuple, try adding a `,` to it:

```py
hang = ('yes',) 

if b in hang:
    print('You fell and died.')
else:
    print('Ok then, keep going.')
```

Comment: My objective is that if the user's answers is 'yes' they should get only the first 'you fell...' message